# Are there any recognised standards for Miracast devices?

Tags: miracast

I have a TV with no casting ability. I also have android phones, windows desktops and linux laptops.

On eBay I can see devices that cost £5 and ones that cost £90.

Something like an SD card has a rating (eg u3) which tells me it works. Is there anything like that for these dongles? Or do I just have to buy the most expensive one I can afford and hope

Answer (score 1):

#### Are there any recognised standards for Miracast devices?

They should be marked with a Wi-Fi CERTIFIED logo:

[image]

> **How does Wi-Fi Alliance help ensure product compatibility and a good user experience for certified products?**
>
> Compatibility and quality are achieved through rigorous testing of
>   Wi-Fi products. Consumers should always look for the Wi-Fi CERTIFIED
>   logo to ensure the best user experience possible.
>
> **What features does Miracast certification test?**
>
> Miracast certification includes testing for audio/video (A/V) latency,
>   quality, and synchronization offset. Testing ensures that devices
>   operate across vendors, provide simplified discovery and setup, meet
>   the minimum display resolution requirement, and implement content
>   protection (when implemented). Miracast devices are also tested for
>   implementation of WPA2™ security. Wi-Fi Alliance members may view
>   details on certification testing in the Wi-Fi CERTIFIED Miracast Test
>   Plan.

Source [Miracast | Wi-Fi Alliance](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/miracast)